# How to update some values in Json Object using C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a Json file (rawResult) that contains few elements that needs to be updated.

Basically any element key in the json that contains "**|translate**", then the value part should be replaced with the text from the respective dictionary (Spanish or English).

```
var rawResult = "{"fields": [{
  "fieldGroup": [
    {
      "key": "Task",
      "type": "input",
      "templateOptions": {
        "label|translate": "task_templateoptions_label",
        "placeholder|translate": "task_templateoptions_placeholder"
      },
      "validation": {
        "messages": {
          "required|translate": "task_validation_messages_required",
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "Sub Task",
      "type": "input",
      "templateOptions": {
        "label|translate": "sub_task_templateOptions_label",
        "placeholder|translate": "sub_task_templateOptions_placeholder"
      }
    }
  ]
}]}"
```

//Dictionary for Spanish

```
Dictionary<string, string> dcSpanish = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dcSpanish.Add("task_templateoptions_label", "Tarea");
dcSpanish.Add("task_templateoptions_placeholder", "Ingrese el nombre de la tarea");
dcSpanish.Add("task_validation_messages_required", "El nombre de la tarea es obligatorio");
dcSpanish.Add("sub_task_templateOptions_label", "Sub tarea");
dcSpanish.Add("sub_task_templateOptions_placeholder", "Ingrese el nombre de la subtarea");
```

//Dictionary for English

```
Dictionary<string, string> dcEnglish = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dcEnglish.Add("task_templateoptions_label", "Task");
dcEnglish.Add("task_templateoptions_placeholder", "Enter the task name");
dcEnglish.Add("task_validation_messages_required", "Task name is required");
dcEnglish.Add("sub_task_templateOptions_label", "Sub task");
dcEnglish.Add("sub_task_templateOptions_placeholder", "Enter the sub task name");
```

So in case the Json result is requested in Spanish, then the output should be,

```
var result = "{"fields": [{
  "fieldGroup": [
    {
      "key": "Task",
      "type": "input",
      "templateOptions": {
        "label": "Tarea",
        "placeholder": "Ingrese el nombre de la tarea"
      },
      "validation": {
        "messages": {
          "required": "El nombre de la tarea es obligatorio",
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "Sub Task",
      "type": "input",
      "templateOptions": {
        "label": "Sub tarea",
        "placeholder": "Ingrese el nombre de la subtarea"
      }
    }
  ]
}]}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query the Json with Linq and update the values where the [`JProperty.Name`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty_Name.htm) contains the required substring (translate). For example

```
var jobject = JObject.Parse(rawResult);
new json = Translate(jobject,dcSpanish);
```

Where `Translate` is defined as

```
string Translate(JObject jo, Dictionary<string,string> translationDictionary)
{
    var keys = jo
                .DescendantsAndSelf()
                .OfType<JProperty>()
                .Where(x=>x.Name.Contains("|translate")).ToList();

    foreach(var item in keys)
    {
        item.Replace(new JProperty(item.Name.Replace("|translate",""), translationDictionary[item.Value.ToString()]));
    }
    return jo.ToString();
}
```

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XWiE1y)

Sample Output

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldGroup": [
        {
          "key": "Task",
          "type": "input",
          "templateOptions": {
            "label": "Tarea",
            "placeholder": "Ingrese el nombre de la tarea"
          },
          "validation": {
            "messages": {
              "required": "El nombre de la tarea es obligatorio"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Sub Task",
          "type": "input",
          "templateOptions": {
            "label": "Sub tarea",
            "placeholder": "Ingrese el nombre de la subtarea"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Works for .NET framework but not for .NET core 3. But still this was helpful and I managed to get it done.